# Routes via application.yaml for Spring Cloud Gateway is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I am sharing the routing code for Spring Cloud Gateway that functions correctly in my application:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("customer-service", r -> r
                        .path("/api/customers/{customerId}")
                        .or()
                        .path("/api/customers")
                        .uri("http://localhost:8082")
                )
                .route("order-service", r -> r
                        .path("/api/orders")
                        .or()
                        .path("/api/orders/**")
                        .or()
                        .path("/api/customers/{customerId}/orders")
                        .or()
                        .path("/api/customers/{customerId}/orders/**")
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081")
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

I wanted to convert this code into application.yml configuration, and here's the modified version:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: customer-service
          uri: http://localhost:8082
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/customers/{customerId}
            - Path=/api/customers
        - id: order-service
          uri: http://localhost:8081
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/orders
            - Path=/api/orders/**
            - Path=/api/customers/{customerId}/orders
            - Path=/api/customers/{customerId}/orders/**
```

Regrettably, the second configuration in the .yml file is not functioning as expected. I anticipated both configurations to be equivalent. Can you please help me identify what I might be overlooking?

Comment: So, the yaml version is "anded" together while the java version has the option of "or". Split up each path into a separate route.